# Percent-encoding of "@" in the local-part of mailto URIs

Tags: uri, mailto

I have a question regarding percent-encoding of email-addresses (RFC 5322) in mailto URIs (RFC 6068 / RFC 3986).

EMail-addresses may contain - among other otherwise forbidden characters - the "@" (at-character) within the `local-part` if it is in double-quotes. That is,

```
<"not@me"@example.org>
```

is a valid address. (Note that I use angle-brackets as delimiters -they are not part of the address.)

This is an example I found in RFC6068, and according to it the corresponding mailto URI is:

```
<mailto:%22not%40me%22@example.org>.
```

Looking at the syntax rules, however, it is not clear to me whether it is necessary to percent encode the "@", or if the following URI would be valid, too:

```
<mailto:%22not@me%22@example.org>.
```

That is: Which rule requires the "@" in the `local-part` to be escaped? Is it because I have percent-encoded the <"> double quotes, and now the rule "@ has to be in double quotes if it appears in the `local-part`" is not applicable anymore?